# How to set custom vector icon for Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to set custom vector icon for Nav Drawer in Toolbar?
`Toolbar.setNavigationIcon(drawable)` works only for bitmaps.

Comment: Convert your vector image to bitmap. And set bitmap to navigation drawer.

Comment: toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu);

Answer (score 0):

> getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
>   getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void showBackButtonOnToolbar(boolean show) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(show);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(show);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_vector_back).mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
            actionBar.setHomeActionContentDescription(getString(R.string.go_back));
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(show);
        }
       }
```